# How to GET row height in QTreeWidget/QTreeView

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

I just want to get the row height from a QTreeWidgetItem. I searched a lot but nothing hits.

What I want to do is to resize the wrap widget which contains a QTreeWidget to enable all rows in the tree are visible (or to say, it will be a bottomless expanding widget).

sizeHint will always return -1 since I have never set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int QTreeWidget::rowHeight(const QModelIndex& index) const
```

Should suffice.

Comment: Thanks but it is a protected function. Is there any public function instead?

Comment: If you're just displaying text, there will be a way by querying the current `QStyle`, but I don't know off the top of my head any details.

Comment: They do contain other widgets. I think I should derive it.

Answer (score 1):

The height of the result of this `QTreeWidget` method, called with a given `QTreeWidgetItem`, does the trick (for `QTreeWidget` -- this isn't usable for `QTreeView`, of course):

```
  QRect QTreeWidget::visualItemRect (const QTreeWidgetItem* item) const;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be solved by adjusting the `sizePolicy` on your QTreeWidget and the wrapper  widget(s) containing the QTreeWidget itself.

I.e. change the size policies to `Expanding` for the vertical property.

Comment: Both are expanding now but it seems not working. I am using designer but I did call setSizePolicy explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

In Designer promote `QTreeView` to some `CTreeView` class defined in `ctreeview.h` like this:

```
#ifndef CTREEVIEW_H
#define CTREEVIEW_H

#include <QTreeView>

class CTreeView : public QTreeView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CTreeView(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QTreeView(parent) {}
    // or 
    // using QTreeView::QTreeView; // Use inherited constructors (C++11)

    int rowHeight(const QModelIndex &index) const {
        return QTreeView::rowHeight(index);
    }
};

#endif // CTREEVIEW_H
```